# parsing json object with array retrofit

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit

I'm trying to parse a the next json object with retrofit 2.1.0 but i don't know why there is not any data witnin the field **data** it's always empty.

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "message": "Upload succesfull",
  "data": [
    {
      "channel": "madrid",
      "date": "20161212221",
      "metadata": {
        "id": "tvmadrid",
        "channel_id": "tvmadrid.com",
        "channel_name": "mad",        
      },
      "promos": []
    },
    {
      "channel": "barca",
      "date": "20161233232",
      "metadata": {
        "id": "tvbarca",
        "channel_id": "tvbarca.com",
        "channel_name": "barca",  
      },
      "promos": []
    }
  ]
}
```

My model class goes here.

> TvChannel

```
public class TvChannel {
private String status;
private String message;
private Data[] data;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}



public Data[] getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Data[] data) {
    this.data = data;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return    "status " + status + "\n"
            + "message " + message + "\n"
            + "Data " + data.toString();
}
```

}

Here is a method that call the API

```
public void getTvChannel(User user, MultipartBody.Part body) {

    //user.getData().getAutenticate(),

    Call<TvChannel> callTvChannel = getAPI().listTvChannel(user.getData().getAutenticate(), body);
    callTvChannel.enqueue(new Callback<TvChannel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TvChannel> call, Response<TvChannel> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {




                Log.d(TAG, "body to string: " + response.body().getStatus());

                TvChannel tvChannel = response.body();



                ArrayList<Data> datas = new ArrayList<Data>(Arrays.asList(response.body().getData()));

                Log.d(TAG + " getTvChannel ", " onResponse: status: " + tvChannel.getStatus() + "  message: " + tvChannel.getMessage() );

                for (Data data : datas) {
                    Log.d(TAG,data.toString());
                }

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG + " getTvChannel", " onResponse " + "Error Code " + response.code());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TvChannel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG + " getTvChannel ", " onFailure " + " Didn't work " + t.getMessage() + " " + t.getCause() + " \n" + Arrays.toString(t.getStackTrace()));


        }
    });
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: try using ArrayList<Data> instead in your model itself

Comment: use this site to convert your `JSOn` into `POGO` `http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: I have solved the problem. Some how i was retrieving the field **data** empty and that was causing the trouble. Thanks everyone for help !!!

Comment: How did you solved your problem? I am not able to retrieve data...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need following....just call `tvChannel.getData()`

`ArrayList<Data> datas = new ArrayList<Data>(Arrays.asList(response.body().getData()));`

Answer (score 0):

Replace array with List like this :

```
@SerializedName("data")
private List<Data> data;

public List<Data> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<Data> data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1) Change in model class
`Data[] data` to `ArrayList<Data>`

2) get "data" like

```
List<Data> datas=tvChannel.getData();
```

i hope it work.

Answer (score 0):

[image]The issue was is in your json,
Please put json to jsonlint.com

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Datum {

@SerializedName("channel")
@Expose
private String channel;
@SerializedName("date")
@Expose
private String date;
@SerializedName("metadata")
@Expose
private Metadata metadata;
@SerializedName("promos")
@Expose
private List<Object> promos = null;

public String getChannel() {
return channel;
}

public void setChannel(String channel) {
this.channel = channel;
}

public String getDate() {
return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
this.date = date;
}

public Metadata getMetadata() {
return metadata;
}

public void setMetadata(Metadata metadata) {
this.metadata = metadata;
}

public List<Object> getPromos() {
return promos;
}

public void setPromos(List<Object> promos) {
this.promos = promos;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Datum> data = null;

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

public List<Datum> getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
this.data = data;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Metadata.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Metadata {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("channel_id")
@Expose
private String channelId;
@SerializedName("channel_name")
@Expose
private String channelName;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getChannelId() {
return channelId;
}

public void setChannelId(String channelId) {
this.channelId = channelId;
}

public String getChannelName() {
return channelName;
}

public void setChannelName(String channelName) {
this.channelName = channelName;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to complicate your model with custom Data class instead using Data import (by the way, what Data class you've imported?):

```
public class TvChannel {
private String status;
private String message;
ArrayList<Data> data;
...
}
public class Data 
{
    String channel;
    int date;
    Metadata metadata;
    String[] promos;//of course, if that's string array
}

public class Metadata
{
    String id;
    String channel_id;
    String channel_name;
}
```

And you can get data like so:

```
TvChannel tvChannel = response.body();
String metadataId = tvChannel.data.get(index).metadata.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it helps.

```
    private String status;
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose() <-- this is important
    private List<Data> data;

    ........


    public List<Data> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Data> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
```